# Body Language, Perhaps?

Tags: cipher, lateral-thinking

You should be able to tell what I'm saying by looking at what I'm doing with my hands and combining the expressions on my face. Just be careful to mind your p's and q's (and your i's and j's).

```
0440061002000400 1810120509300520! 
000010101410133502100645 08000820 1130060502300555 012005400550072000001035.
```

---

Everything above this line is part of the clue. This is my first puzzle; not sure on the difficulty so let me know how you get on. Good luck!

Comment: Does it have anything to do with rot13(frzncuber)?

Answer (score 1):

Nice question!  Partial answer below?

> This uses a clock face and something... 
>  The times are encoded as HHMMHHMM... where HH is a two-digit hour and MM is a two-digit minute.  Some are more than 12, so a 24-hour face may be necessary.

The message can be broken down thus:

> 0440
>  0610
>  0200
>  0400
>   1810
>  1205
>  0930
>  0520!
>  0000
>  1010
>  1410
>  1335
>  0210
>  0645
>   0800
>  0820
>   1130
>  0605
>  0230
>  0555
>   0120
>  0540
>  0550
>  0720
>  0000
>  1035.

Which translates to... still working on it.

Comment: Good start!  Small hint: A letter can have multiple encodings, but any given encoding will only decode back to one letter in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with rot13(frzncuber)?